# How do I replicate iOS 10's Apple Music "Peek and pop action menu"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, 3dtouch, apple-music

iOS 10 has a feature I would like to replicate. When you 3D touch an album in the Apple Music app it opens the menu shown below. However unlike a normal peek and pop, it does not go away when you raise you finger. How do I replicate this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's a 3D Touch and not just a long press? It also works on my iPhone 6+ which doesn't have 3D Touch.

Comment: @Fogmeister Ok so I went and turned off 3D touch. If you notice it shows the same things but at the bottom with a cancel button added. I would actually like to do both. But the issue of how I would do it still stands.

Comment: rather than using a peek and pop segue is it not possible to use some sort of force touch gesture to trigger it? I'm not on my computer at the moment but that's what I'd look for.

Comment: @Fogmeister Ok, Ill look into it. When switching between a hold and a 3d touch it seems like they are done differently. When holding, it animates up from the bottom. When 3D touching it animates in from where the force was applied.

Comment: The nice thing with 3D Touch is that you don't have to lift up your finger to select an action. It's really quick. Wish this was a default component.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I got to replicating it is the following code.. It create a dummy-replica of the Music application.. Then I added the PeekPop-3D-Touch delegates.

However, in the delegate, I add an observer to the gesture recognizer and then cancel the gesture upon peeking but then re-enable it when the finger is lifted. To re-enable it, I did it async because the preview will disappear immediately without the async dispatch. I couldn't find a way around it..

Now if you tap outside the blue box, it will disappear like normal =]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Rwd.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOTnP.jpg

[image]
[image]

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  PeekPopExample
//
//  Created by Brandon Anthony on 2016-07-16.
//  Copyright © 2016 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


class MusicViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var tableView: UITableView!
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.initControllers()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func initControllers() {
        let libraryController = LibraryViewController()
        let forYouController = UIViewController()
        let browseController = UIViewController()
        let radioController = UIViewController()
        let searchController = UIViewController()

        libraryController.title = "Library"
        libraryController.tabBarItem.image = nil

        forYouController.title = "For You"
        forYouController.tabBarItem.image = nil

        browseController.title = "Browse"
        browseController.tabBarItem.image = nil

        radioController.title = "Radio"
        radioController.tabBarItem.image = nil

        searchController.title = "Search"
        searchController.tabBarItem.image = nil

        self.viewControllers = [libraryController, forYouController, browseController, radioController, searchController];
    }


}
```

And the implementation of ForceTouch pausing..

```
//
//  LibraryViewController.swift
//  PeekPopExample
//
//  Created by Brandon Anthony on 2016-07-16.
//  Copyright © 2016 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit


//Views and Cells..

class AlbumView : UIView {
    var albumCover: UIImageView!
    var title: UILabel!
    var artist: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.initControls()
        self.setTheme()
        self.doLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func initControls() {
        self.albumCover = UIImageView()
        self.title = UILabel()
        self.artist = UILabel()
    }

    func setTheme() {
        self.albumCover.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.albumCover.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.albumCover.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray()

        self.title.text = "Unknown"
        self.title.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

        self.artist.text = "Unknown"
        self.artist.textColor = UIColor.lightGray()
        self.artist.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    }

    func doLayout() {
        self.addSubview(self.albumCover)
        self.addSubview(self.title)
        self.addSubview(self.artist)

        let views = ["albumCover": self.albumCover, "title": self.title, "artist": self.artist];
        var constraints = Array<String>()

        constraints.append("H:|-0-[albumCover]-0-|")
        constraints.append("H:|-0-[title]-0-|")
        constraints.append("H:|-0-[artist]-0-|")
        constraints.append("V:|-0-[albumCover]-[title]-[artist]-0-|")

        let aspectRatioConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.albumCover, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.albumCover, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

        self.addConstraint(aspectRatioConstraint)

        for constraint in constraints {
            self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: constraint, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
        }

        for view in self.subviews {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }
}

class AlbumCell : UITableViewCell {
    var firstAlbumView: AlbumView!
    var secondAlbumView: AlbumView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.initControls()
        self.setTheme()
        self.doLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func initControls() {
        self.firstAlbumView = AlbumView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.secondAlbumView = AlbumView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    func setTheme() {

    }

    func doLayout() {
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.firstAlbumView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.secondAlbumView)

        let views: [String: AnyObject] = ["firstAlbumView": self.firstAlbumView, "secondAlbumView": self.secondAlbumView];
        var constraints = Array<String>()

        constraints.append("H:|-15-[firstAlbumView(==secondAlbumView)]-15-[secondAlbumView(==firstAlbumView)]-15-|")
        constraints.append("V:|-15-[firstAlbumView]-15-|")
        constraints.append("V:|-15-[secondAlbumView]-15-|")

        for constraint in constraints {
            self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: constraint, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
        }

        for view in self.contentView.subviews {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }
}



//Details..

class DetailSongViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue()
    }

    /*override func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItem] {
        let regularAction = UIPreviewAction(title: "Regular", style: .default) { (action: UIPreviewAction, vc: UIViewController) -> Void in

        }

        let destructiveAction = UIPreviewAction(title: "Destructive", style: .destructive) { (action: UIPreviewAction, vc: UIViewController) -> Void in

        }

        let actionGroup = UIPreviewActionGroup(title: "Group...", style: .default, actions: [regularAction, destructiveAction])

        return [actionGroup]
    }*/
}











//Implementation..

extension LibraryViewController : UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {
            return nil
        }


        previewingContext.previewingGestureRecognizerForFailureRelationship.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "state", options: .new, context: nil)


        let detailViewController = DetailSongViewController()
        detailViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 300.0)
        previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame
        return detailViewController
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {

        //self.show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: AnyObject?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>?) {
        if let object = object {
            if keyPath == "state" {
                let newValue = change![NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey]!.integerValue
                let state = UIGestureRecognizerState(rawValue: newValue!)!
                switch state {
                case .began, .changed:
                    self.navigationItem.title = "Peeking"
                    (object as! UIGestureRecognizer).isEnabled = false

                case .ended, .failed, .cancelled:
                    self.navigationItem.title = "Not committed"
                    object.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "state")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
                        (object as! UIGestureRecognizer).isEnabled = true
                    })


                case .possible:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class LibraryViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.initControls()
        self.setTheme()
        self.registerClasses()
        self.registerPeekPopPreviews();
        self.doLayout()
    }

    func initControls() {
        self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)
    }

    func setTheme() {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
    }

    func registerClasses() {
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Default")
        self.tableView.register(AlbumCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AlbumCell")
    }

    func registerPeekPopPreviews() {
        //if (self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available) {
            self.registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: self.tableView)
        //}
    }

    func doLayout() {
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

        let views: [String: AnyObject] = ["tableView": self.tableView];
        var constraints = Array<String>()

        constraints.append("H:|-0-[tableView]-0-|")
        constraints.append("V:|-0-[tableView]-0-|")

        for constraint in constraints {
            self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: constraint, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
        }

        for view in self.view.subviews {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return section == 0 ? 5 : 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 ? 44.0 : 235.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return section == 0 ? 75.0 : 50.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0001
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return section == 0 ? "Library" : "Recently Added"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 { //Library
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Default", for: indexPath)

            switch (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row {
            case 0:
                cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Playlists"

            case 1:
                cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Artists"

            case 2:
                cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Albums"

            case 3:
                cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Songs"

            case 4:
                cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Downloads"


            default:
                break
            }
        }

        if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 1 {  //Recently Added
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AlbumCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }

        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Default", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess where I'm lost is that I don't have to swipe up. I know when I 3D touch an text thread and swipe up I get reply options. But when I 3D touch an album, it just animates the screen shown above. No swiping up or anything.

Answer (score 1):

This actually might be done using **UIPreviewInteraction API**.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipreviewinteraction

It is almost similar to the **Peek and Pop API**.

Here we have 2 phases: Preview and Commit which are corresponding to the Peek and Pop in the later API. we have [UIPreviewInteractionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipreviewinteractiondelegate) which gives us the access to the transition through these phases.

So what one should do is, to replicate the above Apple Music Popup,

- Manually show a blur overlay during [didUpdatePreviewTransition](http://previewInteraction(_:didUpdatePreviewTransition:ended:))
- Build an xib of the above menu and show it during [didUpdateCommitTransition](http://previewInteraction(_:didUpdatePreviewTransition:ended:))
- You can make the view stay there on commitTransition phase end.

Actually, apple has built a demo of this in the form of a Chat App.

Download the sample code from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AppChat/Introduction/Intro.html) and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code to replicate like apple music style peek and pop.

### Work like below

[image]

### Explanation

- TopView.xib, TopView.swift (You can customize it)
- PeekAndPopActionView.swift (View for single action, such as download, share ..)
- PeekAndPopController.swift (Present, Dismiss the view)
- ForceTouchGestureRecognizer.swift (Detect Force Touch)

### Usage

```
fileprivate let peekedViewController = PeekAndPopController()

@IBAction func presentAction(_ sender: Any) {
    present(peekedViewController, animated: true)
}

let forceTouch = ForceTouchGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    forceTouch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchAction(_:)))
    forceTouch.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(forceTouch)

    let download = PeekAndPopActionView(text: "Download", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "btnDownload"), handler: {
        print("Download Action")
    })

    let playNext = PeekAndPopActionView(text: "Play Next", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "btnDownload"), handler: {
        print("Play Next Action")
    })

    let playLast = PeekAndPopActionView(text: "Play Later", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "btnDownload"), handler: {
        print("Play Last Action")
    })

    let share = PeekAndPopActionView(text: "Share", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "btnDownload"), handler: {
        print("Share Action")
    })

    peekedViewController.addAction(download)
    peekedViewController.addAction(playNext)
    peekedViewController.addAction(playLast)
    peekedViewController.addAction(share)
    peekedViewController.topView = TopView().loadNib()

    peekedViewController.topView?.handler = {
        print("Play Play Play")
    }
}

@objc func touchAction(_ gesture: ForceTouchGestureRecognizer) {
    print(#function, gesture.touch?.location(in: view) ?? "")
    present(peekedViewController, animated: true)
}
```