# 3D Touch Peek View Like Apple Music

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch, force-touch

I know how to add 3d touch peek and pop to my `UITableView` by using `previewingContext:`. How do I add a stationary peek view like Apple's music app? Basically, you 3d touch on the `UITableViewCell`, and the peek view shows and stays there. Go check it out for yourself on an iPhone, but here is a screenshot.

[image]

Basically, I just want to know how they did this. I want my users to be able to interact with this view as well (like pressing buttons and stuff). Any ideas?

Comment: well... they probably started the morning with a coffee then there might have been a meeting and finally they just made the implementation.

Comment: @holex Haha! That was good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replicate iOS 10's Apple Music "Peek and pop action menu"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416862/how-do-i-replicate-ios-10s-apple-music-peek-and-pop-action-menu)

Comment: @JacobCavin Hello! Did you figure out how to do this by any chance??

Comment: @MikeJSChoi No I did not. I moved on to something else but may come back to this soon. I would recommend checking out Apple’s documentation